# Is there a way to interpolate mixin name in Stylus

Tags: css, stylus

```
colors = {
    base: gray,
    info: blue
}

for key, val in colors
    .skin-bg-{key}
        background val
    .skin-bd-{key}
        border 1px solid val
```

Now i can use generated classes inside my markup like:

```
div.skin-bg-base.skin-bd-info
```

or inside styles via @extends

```
.item-card
    @extends .skin-bg-base
    @extends .skin-bd-info
```

But after reading many of resources that mixin is better than @extends, i've tried to generate the same name mixins, but no result

```
for key, val in colors
    {'skin-bg-' + key}()
        background val
```

or

```
mixins = {}
for key, val in colors
    mixin[{'skin-bg-' + key}]()
        background val
```

not works =(

It is possible in stylus?

Answer (score 1):

Use a single mixin and pass the key as an argument.  You can use Stylus's [`+cache()` function](http://stylus-lang.com/docs/bifs.html#cachekeys) to prevent duplicate rules from being emitted, just like with `@extend`.

Here is your example using cacheable mixins:

```
colors = {
    base: gray,
    info: blue
}
skin-bg(key)
  +cache(key)
    background: colors[key]
skin-bd(key)
  +cache(key)
    border: 1px solid colors[key]

.item-card
    skin-bg: base
    skin-bd: info
.other-card
    skin-bg: base
```

Compiles into the following:

```
.item-card,
.other-card {
  background: #808080;
}
.item-card {
  border: 1px solid #00f;
}
```